# wso2 identity server integration with esb

Tags: web-services, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am a beginner to WSO2. I am facing some challenges in integrating WSO2 identity server with ESB. I followed the "**http://wso2.org/library/articles/2010/10/using-xacml-fine-grained-authorization-wso2-platform/**" blog. I am getting some errors related to authenticating the user when using entitlement component in ESB.
Following is the error i get in console:-

> [2012-07-06 19:23:42,312] ERROR - EntitlementMediator User name not
>   provided for the Entitlement mediator - can't proceed [2012-07-06
>   19:23:42,312] ERROR - EntitlementMediator Error occured while
>   evaluating the policy org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: User name
>   not provided for the Entitlement mediator - can't proceed     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.mediator.EntitlementMediator.mediate(EntitlementMediator.java:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:114)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:154)
>     at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingMethod(ServerWorker.java:409)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:173)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Can any one please help me understanding it.

Thanks in advance.
Charan

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this article[1] as to see how you can secure.

[1] http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/06/securing-web-service-integration

Answer (score 0):

This is because the service request to the ESB proxy service is not secured using a username token based policy. Please make sure that proxy is secured with Username token based security scenario as per the article and your client is sending the username token credentials in the WS Security header of the request to the proxy service.